How to ignore functions matching pattern in pyright?
Despite ignoring vcr, pyright still reports an error. Why am I still seeing this error:
[Pyright] Arguments missing for parameters "instance", "args", "kwargs" (3:5)

# test_foo.py

@pytest.mark.skip
class TestPublisher:
    @vcr.use_cassette('cassettes/test_publish_post.yaml')

# pyproject.toml

[tool.pyright]
ignore = ["*vcr*"]

Actually I don't think pyproject.toml is respected at all in pyright after trying:
[tool.pyright]
ignore = [".","*"]
exclude = [".","*"]


"Actually I don't think pyproject.toml is respected at all": Are you actually using Pylance (VSCode extension) instead of Pyright (CLI)?

The ignore configuration is for the paths of files which you do not want any diagnostics:

ignore [array of paths, optional]: Paths of directories or files whose diagnostic output (errors and warnings) should be suppressed even if they are an included file or within the transitive closure of an included file.

Your test_foo.py doesn't match the path *vcr*, and hence not ignored.
Note: If you are using Pylance, either edit the Ignore setting or select workspace for the Diagnostic Mode setting.
